# NO puedo llamar a una función en un módulo

Tags: python, crud, sqlite3

Estoy intentando crear un simple programa para manejo de bases de datos, el problema es que al llamar a la función que está en un módulo distinto, el programa falla.

Aquí está el código del archivo `main`, no he avanzando mucho.

```
import sqlite3
import Utilidades

Nombre_De_Programa = "Sistema Univesidad Nacional"
logo = [
"  ____    _   _   _   _ ", 
" / ___|  | | | | | \ | |",
" \___ \  | | | | |  \| |",
"  ___) | | |_| | | |\  |",
" |____/   \___/  |_| \_| "]
                        
print(Nombre_De_Programa)
for i in logo:
    print (i)

database = sqlite3.connect("SUN")

lector = database.cursor()

try:
    lector.execute("CREATE TABLE USUARIOS (USUARIO VARCHAR(56), ID INTEGER, ROL VARCHAR(15))")
except:
    pass

condition = True

while condition ==  True:

    print("Bienvenido, seleccione la operacion que desea realizar")
    print("1.) Añadir usuario")
    print("2.) Consultar usuario")
    print("3.) Modificar usuario")
    print("4.) Eliminar usuario")
    print("5.) Salir")
    opcion = int(input("Digite la opcion: "))

    if (opcion == 1):
        Utilidades.agregar()
    if (opcion == 2):
        pass
    if (opcion == 3):
        pass
    if (opcion == 4):
        pass
    if (opcion == 5):
        salida = input("Esta seguro que desea salir Y|N: ")
        if (salida == "Y"):
            condition = False
        else:
            pass

database.close()
```

Este es el archivo utilidades, al llamarlo desde el archivo main dirá que el lector no esta definido, pero si lo importo me dará un error de importación circular. Por favor ayuda.

```
def agregar ():

    a = input("Digite el nombre del usuario: ")
    b = int(input("Digite el ID del usuario: "))
    c = input("Digite el rol de usuario: ")

    lector.execute("INSERT INTO USUARIOS VALUES(?,?,?)", a,b,c)

    lector.commit()
```

Comment: Estas en SO en español por lo que las preguntas debe estar en este idioma

Comment: OH vale gracias, lo siento es la costumbre. Ya mismo lo edito.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar el concepto de *scope* en python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces y https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html. cada modulo tiene su propio *scope*(alcance), la solución en tu caso es trivial: cambia a `def agregar(lector):` y `Utilidades.agregar(lector)`
`